# installed gcc include path doesn't seem correct and library and header mismatch reported

Tags: c, linux, gcc, build, kernel-module

This is a long but simple basic question. So anyone familiar could answer to my questions.
I have a simple program below on my CentOS 6.4 system. (have it unnder ~/test)
I wanted to test insmod and rmmod.

```
#include <linux/module.h>

static int __init hello_world( void )
{
  printk( "hello world!\n" );
  return 0;
}

static void __exit goodbye_world( void )
{
  printk( "goodbye world!\n" );
}

module_init( hello_world );
module_exit( goodbye_world );
```

When I did

```
gcc -o hello_world hello_world.c
```

I got

```
hello_world.c:1:26: error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory
hello_world.c:3: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'hello_world'
hello_world.c:9: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'goodbye_world'
hello_world.c:14: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
hello_world.c:14: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
hello_world.c:15: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
hello_world.c:15: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
```

So I figured the include path is not setup correctly. I searched where this linux/module.h is located and found linux/module.h is under /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/module.h.
(When I give 'uname -a', I get
Linux stph45.etri.re.kr 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 13 00:26:49 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
So this /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include is the right kernel header directory.)
 Then I tried again like this

```
gcc -I/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/ -o hello_world hello_world.c
```

and got

```
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/list.h:7,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from hello_world.c:1:
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/prefetch.h:14:27: error: asm/processor.h: No such file or directory
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/prefetch.h:15:23: error: asm/cache.h: No such file or directory
... more lines ...
```

I found this architecture dependent header file in /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h. So this time I did

```
gcc -I/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/arch/x86/include -I/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include -o hello_world hello_world.c
```

providing the separate header path for the arch dependent files. Now I have these errors..

```
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:45,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/prefetch.h:14,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/list.h:7,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from hello_world.c:1:
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/kernel.h:949:2: warning: #warning Attempt to use kernel headers from user space, see http:
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/prefetch.h:14,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/list.h:7,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from hello_world.c:1:
/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'struct'
.... more lines ....
```

I think this 'Attempt to user kernel headers' is ok in this case. and I have to find the cause of "error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'struct'" error.

I think my gcc (I guess it came with the CentOS.) seems to have some problem. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my gcc installation? Seeing below message, there are some mismatches and I don't know the procedures for the cures. (afraid to ruin the whole development tool chain which is dependent on gcc)

```
ckim@stph45:~/testprog] echo "" | gcc -o /tmp/tmp.o -v -x c -
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' '/tmp/tmp.o' '-v' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/cc1 -quiet -v - -quiet -dumpbase - -mtune=generic -auxbase - -version -o /tmp/ccWAQshz.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), GMP version 4.3.1, MPFR version 2.4.1.
warning: GMP header version 4.3.1 differs from library version 4.3.2.
warning: MPFR header version 2.4.1 differs from library version 2.4.2.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 11481e4aa93ef024f1be70ed47ae45e3
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' '/tmp/tmp.o' '-v' '-mtune=generic'
 as -V -Qy -o /tmp/ccTYQoBw.o /tmp/ccWAQshz.s
GNU assembler version 2.20.51.0.2 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version version 2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6 20100205
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' '/tmp/tmp.o' '-v' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr --build-id -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o /tmp/tmp.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../.. /tmp/ccTYQoBw.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You need to know, how to compile linux kernel module. It's different from compiling any other typical C program. do some searching to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile a kernel module, you are supposed to write a Makefile to setup the kernel path and other environment variable.

You can use the below Makefile to build you kernel module

```
obj-m := hello_world.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build  M=$(PWD) modules

clean: 
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build  M=$(PWD) clean
```

Copy the above contents to file name Makefile in the same directory as that of the source.

Just enter **$ make** command to build the module. The output would be **hello_world.ko** in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the header/library mismatch

```
warning: GMP header version 4.3.1 differs from library version 4.3.2.
warning: MPFR header version 2.4.1 differs from library version 2.4.2.
```

it may not be a problem here. I suppose that GCC was compiled with GMP 4.3.1 and MPFR 2.4.1, but after that, the GMP and MPFR shared libraries were upgraded to ABI-compatible versions 4.3.2 and 2.4.2 respectively. If this is the case, this is allowed.